# About maintenance plan rebuild indexing

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

How to configure rebuild and reorganization in maintenance plan? Please tell me step by step, for SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: Ya but i did n't get clear information

Comment: While executing rebuild indexing in mainteance plan geting error like could not generate mail an exception occurred while executing a transact sql statement or batch no golbal profile is configured specify a profile name in the@profile_name  parameter, how fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up a default profile for your database mail profile. Under Management -> Database mail profile, right click and select Database Mail configuration. A wizard will pop up. Select Manage profile security. As shown below, atleast one of your mail profiles should have been set as Default Profile ('Yes')

[image]